# High Charts Polar / Spider chart with off-graph y-axis labels

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a Spider graph that has the y-axes labels offset with extended gridlines.

Is this possible to achieve with just one graph, or do I have to create two separate graphs and overlay them? I've tried ticklines, gridlines, and they all get stuck in the polar coordinates.

[image: What I'm trying to accomplish]

Here's my attempt at trying to accomplish this:
http://jsfiddle.net/6d6jrfhs/3/

```
{

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
        text: "# of Impacts",
        x: -80
    },

    pane: {
        size: '80%',
        startAngle: 0,
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Back', 'Left', 'Front', 'Top',
                'Right'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        offset: 0,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: -100,
            y: 0
        },
        tickLength: 500,
        plotLines: [{
        color: 'red', // Color value
        dashStyle: 'longdashdot', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
        value: 40000, // Value of where the line will appear
        width: 1 // Width of the line    
        }]
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },

    series: [{
            type:'area',
        name: 'Low Impact',
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000],
        pointPlacement: 'off'
    }, {
        type:'area',
        name: 'Actual Spending',
        data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000],
        pointPlacement: 'off'
    }]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This demo shows how to find labels (SVG elements) in the chart object and create additional gridline using **SVG Renderer**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/eg7p3r48/

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    var yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
        renderer = this.renderer,
      label = yAxis.ticks[0].label;

      renderer.path(['M', label.xy.x, label.xy.y, 'l', label.xy.x - xOffset - 30, 0]).attr({
        stroke: 'black',
        'stroke-width': 1
      }).add();

  }
}
```

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: and for each label in the y axis?

Comment: Just iterate `yAxis.ticks` array and create a path for each label.